# Mysql select count distinct and select distinct

Tags: php, mysql

So as example, in the picter bellow, I have simple table called `students`. Some student has GPA = NULL. 
I have a query to count DISTINCT GPA values :

```
SELECT count( DISTINCT GPA ) FROM `students`
```

[image]

Result, as expected, 2.

But also, I thought, I can count using PHP, and just write:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GPA FROM `students`
```

But why the result is 3 lines(not 2 as expected)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Count function is defined to ignore NULL values. 
When you select DISTINCT rows, NULL is considered. Thats why you get 3 rows. It is by design.
See documentation for COUNT: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

Comment: SELECT COUNT( * ) GPA FROM `students` gives result = 4

Comment: Yes. Look at the documentation I´ve added. You´ll see that Count(*) is defined as RowCount.

Comment: Please do not only upcode the answer but also mark them as correct so that others do not need to look into you question. Thanks.

Comment: wait a minute, be tolerant)